# How to make MatrixForm display row horizontally as a real row vector and not vertically as a column vector?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there a way to make `MatrixForm` display a row vector horizontally on the line and not vertically as it does for column vectors? As this confuses me sometimes. Do you think it will be hard to write wrapper around matrix form to adjust this behavior?

For example, here is a 2 by 2 matrix. The rows display the same as the columns. Both are shown vertical.

[image]

Question: Is it possible to make `MatrixForm` display row vectors laid out horizontally and not vertically?

Sorry if this was asked before, a quick search shows nothing.

thanks

**update (1)**

fyi, this is in Matlab, it prints rows horizontally and column vertically *automatically*, I was hoping for something like this. But I'll use suggestion by Heike below for now as it solves this at the cost of little extra typing.

[image]

**update (2)**
Using Hilderic solution is nice also, I always had hard time printing 3D matrix in a way I can read it. Here it is now using the `{}` trick

[image]

Comment: `MatrixForm[twoRowsMatrix[[1, All]], TableDirections -> Row]` should work.

Comment: @Heike, thanks! that helps. I wish MatrixForm would figure this out byitself, but I guess it would be hard. Since passing it a list, it does not know if it a row vector or a column vector! I guess I just have to add this option now whenever I know what I am printing is a row. This help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For both `arrayname[[All,1]]` and `arrayname[[1,All]]`, `Part` delivers a vector, and MatrixForm has no way of determining which "orientation" it has.  Accordingly, it always prints vectors as columns.

About the only thing you can do is provide your own output routine for row vectors, e.g., by wrapping it in an enclosing list, converting it back to a (single-row) matrix:

```
rowVector[a_List] := MatrixForm[{a}]
columnVector = MatrixForm   (*for symmetry*)
```

It's still up to you to remember whether a vector came from a row or a column, though.

Comment: For "about the only thing you can do", read "the only was I know how to do it".  Thanks for the information about `TableDirections`, Heike.  I'd probably still use helper functions, but this saves rewrapping the row.

Comment: +1, I like your solution, easy to just add an extra `{}` when needed. I also tried on printing 3D matrix, and does print the 3D matrix the way I like it now, where before it was confusing. Please see edit (2).

Answer (score 5):

Or you could just cook up your own RowForm function, e.g.:

```
RowForm[(m_)?VectorQ] := Row[{"(",Row[m,"  "], 
     ")"}, "\[MediumSpace]"];
```

Then

```
RowForm[twoRowsMatrix[[All,1]]]
```

looks kind of o.k.

Alternatively, if you really just care about displaying vectors, you could do:

```
twoRowsMatrix = {{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}};

TakeColumn[m_?MatrixQ, i_] := (Print[MatrixForm[#]]; #) &@m[[All, i]];
TakeRow[m_?MatrixQ, i_] := (Print[MatrixForm[{#}]]; #) &@m[[i]];
TakeColumn[twoRowsMatrix, 1]
TakeRow[twoRowsMatrix, 1]
```

Comment: +1, good solution, but you really should not get in the habit of using UpperCase first letter for user defined functions. someone looking at RowForm function in the code might think it is a build-in function.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the `()` part, then you can append with `,{}`, wrap in curly brackets, and use `TableForm` or `Grid` instead:

```
vec = {x, y, z};
TableForm[{vec, {}}]
Grid[{vec, {}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

When I get worried about this, I use {{a,b,c}} to specify a row of a,b,c (they can be any kind of list) and Transpose[{{a,b,c}}] to specify a column of a,b,c.

```
MatrixForm[a = RandomInteger[{0, 6}, {2, 2}]]
MatrixForm[b = RandomInteger[{0, 6}, {2, 2}]]
MatrixForm[c = RandomInteger[{0, 6}, {2, 2}]]
w = {a, b, c};
MatrixForm[w]
w = {{a, b, c}};
MatrixForm[w]
w = Transpose[{{a, b, c}}];
MatrixForm[w]
```